# Is there a way to generate a license report for a whole maven repository?

Tags: maven, license-maven-plugin

I want to check the licenses of my maven repository. I know how to generate a license report for a maven project (see [Maven Project Info Report](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/license-mojo.html)) but not for a whole repository.

Comment: First you like to Maven Project Info Report is wrong. This is the correct location: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/license-mojo.html . Apart from that: Are you talking about your local cache $HOME/.m2/repository or from your repository manager ?

Comment: I have corrected the link. Thanks for your advice. I'm talking about my local repository.

Comment: May be you could take a look at: http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/